# Move a child out of parent div and into a new div in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Say I have 2 parent divs (pictures included), would it be possible to move a child from div2 into div1 only when browser transitions from screen size of md to xs?

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h1> 1 </h1>
    <h1> 2 </h1> 
    <!-- 5 goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h1> 3 </h1>
    <h1> 4 </h1>
    <h1> 5 </h1> <!--- move this -->
  </div>
```

So move h1 with text of 5 under h1 with text of 2?
I'm thinking no because the children are containe in div elements? So pulling it won't help

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A CSS only solution**

If the content in div #5 is not large and static I would duplicate the content in both containing divs and then hide the content using responsive utilities to hide and show the divs at the different breakpoints http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

**Javascript solution**

look into http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

```
$( "div.third" ).replaceWith( $( ".first" ) );
```

Comment: Yep thanks, that's what I was thinking of doing using "visible-xs" and "hidden-xs" wasn't sure if there was another way